# Regex split comma delimiter value enclosed by double quote

Tags: c#, regex

This is the sample input and output format that i tend to achieve. I have work on several solution on splitting with regex online but it do not satisfied all conditions. Hope someone can help. I need a regex splitting solution for this. Please do not suggest library. Thank you.

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
Regex lineSplit = new Regex("(?:^|,)(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
foreach (Match match in lineSplit.Matches(line))
{
  values.Add(match.Value.TrimStart(',').Replace("\"", ""));
}
```

---

```
"123","456","789"
123
456
789

"123"","456","789"
123"
456
789

"123"2","456","789"
123"2
456
789

"123",2","456","789"
123",2
456
789

"123","2","456","789"
123
2
456
789
```

Comment: Do you really need a regex for this? Why not `line.Replace("\"", "").Split(',');` ?

Comment: @FelyppOliveira That wouldn't keep the embedded quotes as per his required output.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I see your point. I missed this detail. Your approach works better...

Comment: @FelyppOliveira I deleted my approach too, since there was a case where it didn't work either. :)

Comment: How about `\A\"(?<entry>.*?)\"(,\"(?<entry>.*?)\")*\Z`?

Comment: This is easy if you don't use RegExp: `var output = input.Trim('\"').Split(new[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();`

Comment: Yes, I have [just finished a similar demo](https://ideone.com/k8qRkC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a non-regex approach is also considered, I suggest getting rid of the initial and trailing quotes (with e.g. `.Substring(1, s.Length - 2)`, or `.Trim('"')`), and then splitting the strings with `","`:

Use

```
var elements = line.Substring(1, s.Length - 2).Split(new[] {"\",\""}, StringSplitOptions.None))
```

See [C# demo](https://ideone.com/k8qRkC):

```
var s = "\"123\",\"456\",\"789\"";
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("|", s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2).Split(new[] {"\",\""}, StringSplitOptions.None)));
s = "\"123\"\",\"456\",\"789\"";
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("|", s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2).Split(new[] {"\",\""}, StringSplitOptions.None)));
s = "\"123\"2\",\"456\",\"789\"";
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("|", s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2).Split(new[] {"\",\""}, StringSplitOptions.None)));
s = "\"123\",2\",\"456\",\"789\"";
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("|", s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2).Split(new[] {"\",\""}, StringSplitOptions.None)));
s = "\"123\",\"2\",\"456\",\"789\"";
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("|", s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2).Split(new[] {"\",\""}, StringSplitOptions.None)));
```

Output:

```
123|456|789
123"|456|789
123"2|456|789
123",2|456|789
123|2|456|789
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a regex like this:

`(?<=^"|,").*?(?=","|"$)`

Explaining:

`(?<=^"|,")     # positive lookbehind: one quote with comma before or at the start
.*?             # match everything returning at first match 
(?=","|"$)      # positive lookahead: one quote with comma and quote after or at the end`

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/xV7kQ0/3)

Hope it helps.